# Proper quotation in mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

There some problem in my query.

```js
$test = "Don't look at me";

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO testtable SET testfield = '".$test."' ");
```

Notice there is a single quote on the string. When I execute it, it returns an error like

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't look at me ... 
If I remove the single quote in the string, it works fine. So how can I save the string into the database without removing the single quote?

Comment: `$test = "Don\'t look at me";` or use `aadslashes()`.

Comment: or use mysqli_real_escape_string function

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$test)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. It is secures and also prevent your query with `sql injection`. also your `table name` and `column name` in `backtick`

```
$test = "Don't look at me";

$val=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$test); //here you can pass your connection variable

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `testtable` SET `testfield` = '".$val."' ");
```

Read Documemt [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: will that makes the string to be save on the database be the same after it is being save?

Comment: like on the code, the string is `Don't look at me` and on the database, the string will still be `Don't look at me`

Comment: also read my comment for table name and column name and don't forget to pass connection variable in `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: why is it that i need to put `backtick` on the table name and column?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape them properly-

```
$test = "Don\'t look at me";
```

or use `aadslashes()`

```
"INSERT INTO testtable SET testfield = '" .addslashes($test). "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use

`mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,escapestring)`

mysqli_real_escape_string() function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to escape values by yourself. Use prepared statements for that: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php ,
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php